# Set a global timer in a php web environment

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function in PHP that counts how many times a function is used by all the users.

If this function has been used, let's say, 30 times, then it should block access for some minutes and then reset the counter to 0.

Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: I'm still thinking how to make it, the counter part shouldn't be hard to do: maybe I could store the request number on a file and fetch it every time, but this is a solution I'd like avoid. What worries me the most is the timer part maybe with the `sleep()` function , but I'm afraid that this will affect just a single user, not everyone.

Comment: Store a timestamp alongside the counter value. This time all processes can consider the same timeout value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no problem, even trivial, if all usages take place within a single process. You just use a global or static counter variable and increment it. As long as the process is running you can access that value.

However I assume you are talking about a web environment and the php function being part of a script executed by the http server? Sorry, but you don't mention that...

In that case things get more complex, since it is not a single process any more. You require some sort of persistent storage. Typical scenarios use a database, a file or shared memory for this. These allow different processes to access a shared counter value.

Comment: Yes, it is on a web environment, with concurrent requests. I was just wondering if there were different solutions than DB or file, but it seems there aren't.

Comment: So, what solution for shared access do you select? What are your requirements?

Comment: I can only think to a transactional MySQL DB query

Comment: Why do you exclude the two other suggestions? And when using a relational database engine, why transactional? It is an atomic query...

Comment: Because it is very important that `timesUsed<=requestCap`. If cap is 30 and two users read 29 and can access the function, it can be a problem.

Comment: You certainly can guarantee that using other options, or am I mistaken? Lock the table before incrementing the counter, lock the file inside the filesystem, lock the shared memory pool...

Comment: I'm new to php and dbms. I've also found the `flock()` function, but this means that can be performed one access at time? I could also lock the table since it is a myisam db.

Comment: Yes and yes. Note that when you go for a file system based approach `flock()` has blocking character. This is what you want. A file based solution is the least efficient option here. But it is reliable and easy to setup. Oh, and if you are using the myisam storage engine inside MySql then you cannot use transactions anyway. So one thing less to consider :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a database anyway I'd say the easiest way is to increment a value in the table of a database. You could also store a timestamp in the same step. The (incremented) value can easily be read by the next calling function afterwards. If you have no database you may also use a text/XML file.

Comment: This could be a solution, but I'd rather not query the db or fetch data from file at every request, this seems not efficient.